# Can't install apex on Windows

Tags: apex

I want to install [apex](https://github.com/nvidia/apex) on my computer with Windows 10 and cuda 9.0. I know apex is not recommended to be installed on Windows, but I still very much want to try it. I used These two commands provided on [apex official website](https://github.com/nvidia/apex):

```
pip install -v --no-cache-dir --global-option="--cpp_ext" --global-option="--cuda_ext"
```

and

```
pip install -v --no-cache-dir
```

but under both conditions got the error:

```
ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")
```

The whole message is:

```
>pip install -v --no-cache-dir --global-option="--cpp_ext" --global-option="--cuda_ext"
C:\Users\Huiqi Xue\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py:211: UserWarning: Disabling all use of wheels due to the use of --build-options / --global-options / --install-options.
  cmdoptions.check_install_build_global(options)
Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\HUIQIX~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-9dmaw_wt
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\HUIQIX~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-tracker-rf4_u0bh
Created requirements tracker 'C:\\Users\\HUIQIX~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-rf4_u0bh'
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\HUIQIX~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bflvtp4e
Cleaning up...
Removed build tracker 'C:\\Users\\HUIQIX~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-rf4_u0bh'
ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Huiqi Xue\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\Huiqi Xue\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 293, in run
    self.name, wheel_cache
  File "C:\Users\Huiqi Xue\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 252, in populate_requirement_set
    '(see "pip help %(name)s")' % opts)
pip._internal.exceptions.CommandError: You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")
Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
1 location(s) to search for versions of pip:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably getting the error because you missed the dot at the end of the command:

```
pip install -v --no-cache-dir --global-option="--cpp_ext" --global-option="--cuda_ext" .
```